# Given the scalar equation, $8x + 9y = -45$, write a vector equation?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

scalar equation:

$8x + 9y = -45$

**Attempt:**

I took the $y$-intercept and the $x$-intercept of the scalar equation and got
$(-5.625, 0)$ and $(0,-5)$

By subtracting the points i got $[5.625, -5]$

so my vector equation was
$[x,y] = [0,-5] + t[5.625, -5]$

the correct answer is
$[0,-5] + t[-9,8]$

How did they get this??? Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is completely correct, you just have to remember that a line equation in the form:

$$\vec{A}+\lambda\vec{B}$$

Is true for any $\vec{A}$ on the line and any scalar multiple of the direction vector $\vec{B}$. In this case they have multiplied your direction vector by $-1.6$, so you have:

$$\begin{pmatrix}-9 \\ 8\end{pmatrix}=-1.6\begin{pmatrix}5.625 \\ -5\end{pmatrix}$$

They have likely done this so the direction vector has only integer components.

Answer (score 1):

You did nothing wrong, but the answer uses $[-9,8]$ instead of $[5.625,-5]$.

This is because $$5.625\times (-1.6)=-9,$$$$-5\times (-1.6)=8.$$ We can do this because we have a parameter $t$ in front of this orientation vector.